# AVAudioPlayer crash in Xcode?

Tags: crash, avaudioplayer

When I run my app in from Xcode to my iPhone7, it crashes at this line:

> audioNSURL    NSURL   "file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/016483D7-D06F-4639-A026-CCD0B1F4B31F/Solo%20Mission.app/spaceMusic.mp3"  0x000000028217eac0

Something to do with the AVAudioPlayer inside of the GameViewController which gives me this error message:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x48)

Please help with this issue I have already checked the build phases and the file is there. Below is all of the code.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

var backingAudio = AVAudioPlayer()


 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "spaceMusic", ofType: "mp3")
    let audioNSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)

    do { backingAudio = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioNSURL as URL) }
    catch { return print("Cannot Find The Audio") }

    backingAudio.numberOfLoops = -1
    backingAudio.volume = 1
    backingAudio.play()
```

Comment: Have you crosschecked that your file exists and that the name + filetype is 100% correct?

Comment: @doingSomeSwiftHere Yes, I have checked already. The strange part is that the game + audio work perfectly fine in the simulation for any device. It only crashes when I attempt to run the game on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

I tried so many different ways, but finally I solved the problem. I just needed to write the code differently. Here's what I wrote instead:

```
        var player: AVAudioPlayer?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


        func initializePlayer() -> AVAudioPlayer? {
            guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "spaceMusic", ofType: "mp3") else {
                return nil
            }

            return try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        }
        player = initializePlayer()
        player?.play()
```

To be honest, I don't quite understand why this works. But, I would appreciate any explanation given.